# html2canvas: capturing screenshot of remote website

Tags: php, javascript, html2canvas

Folks,

I am new to js and this I am having trouble capturing and taking a screenshot of a remote website. Can someone point me in the right direction

I keep getting this error:

**Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'html2canvas' index.php:4201
capture index.php:4201
onclick**

My code is index.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Hawk-Eye: Have a look at what others are upto</title>
<script type="text/javascript"        src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Hawk-eye/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/Hawk-    eye/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="target">
<?php

 $homepage= file_get_contents('http://www.yahoo.com');
 echo $homepage;
?>
</div>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save.php" id="myForm">
<input type="hidden" name="img_val" id="img_val" value="" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function capture() {
    $('#target').html2canvas({
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
            //Set hidden field's value to image data (base-64 string)
            $('#img_val').val(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
            //Submit the form manually
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    });
}

</script>

<input type="submit" value="Take Screenshot" onclick="capture();" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `http://localhost/Hawk-    eye/jquery.plugin.html2canvas.js` you sure it is correct path ?

Comment: dev-null-dweller: I think was a path issue. Php-storm did an auto fix by importing it from the right path. I feel like a noob :/

Answer (score 0):

Download html4canvas and import it as

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js?rev032"></script>
```